# How to make multiple pages when clicked on link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two (or more) links.

First is link (example) :  http://website.com

Second is code with: `<div>   </div>`

How can I make them both open when I click on a single link?

For example, a link entitled "click here" which, when clicked, will open two different blank windows.

Comment: Bind a `click` event handler to the link, and call `window.open()` twice in it.

Answer (score 1):

This is only done with Javascript. Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://mywebsite1.com'); window.open('http://mywebsite1.com');">Click Me</a>
```